# Erro de namespace name 'LinqToDb' could not be found

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

Baixei o Linq2Db.Firebird via Nuget e alterei o arquivo conforme manda o tutorial:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostSpecific="True"                          #>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs"                                                 #>
<#@ include file="$(ProjectDir)LinqToDB.Templates\LinqToDB.Firebird.ttinclude"       #>
<#@ include file="$(ProjectDir)LinqToDB.Templates\PluralizationService.ttinclude"    #>
<#
    /*
        1. Copy this file to a folder where you would like to generate your data model,
           rename it, and delete .txt extension. For example:

            MyProject
                DataModels
                    MyDatabase.tt

        2. Modify the connection settings below to connect to your database.

        3. Add connection string to the web/app.config file:

            <connectionStrings>
                <add name="dados" connectionString="DataSource=localhost;Database=E:\OneDrive\VisualStudio\BancoFirebird\BancoFirebird\DADOS.GDB;User Id=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey" providerName="Firebird" />
            </connectionStrings>

        4. To access your database use the following code:

            using (var db = new MyDatabaseDB())
            {
                var q =
                    from c in db.Customers
                    select c;

                foreach (var c in q)
                    Console.WriteLine(c.ContactName);
            }

        5. See more at https://github.com/linq2db/t4models/blob/master/Templates/ReadMe.LinqToDB.md.
    */

    NamespaceName = "DataModels";

    LoadFirebirdMetadata("localhost", @"E:\OneDrive\VisualStudio\BancoFirebird\BancoFirebird\DADOS.GDB");
//  LoadFirebirdMetadata(string server, string database, string uid, string password);
//  LoadFirebirdMetadata(string connectionString);

    GenerateModel();
#>
```

Fiz os passos de 1 a 3:

1. Copiei o arquivo para uma pasta chamada DataModels e renomeei para dados.tt
2. Alterei a configuração, como podem ver no arquivo:

   LoadFirebirdMetadata("localhost", @"E:\OneDrive\VisualStudio\BancoFirebird\BancoFirebird\DADOS.GDB");
3. Alterei a connection string, como também podem ver no arquivo acima e incluí no app.config.

porém, continuo recebendo o erro:

```
Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'LinqToDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BancoFirebird
```

Nessa linha: <#@ include `file="$(ProjectDir)LinqToDB.Templates\LinqToDB.Firebird.ttinclude"       #>`

Sendo que já fui na pasta e vi que o arquivo se encontra lá.

O que eu devo fazer?